# Filter by the id of an embedded entity in Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Let's say I have

```
@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable{

    @Id private Long id = null;
    @Index private Driver driver = null;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Driver implements Serializable{

    @Id private Long id = null;
    ...
}
```

How can I filter a Car entity by the id of his driver entity in Objectify? Something like `ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("driver.id", someId).first().now();`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, you can't. And even if you could, it would almost certainly be something awkward like `filter("driver.__key__", Key.create(Driver.class, someId))`. This is getting pretty far into unexplored territory. Unless you're super familiar with GAE and Objectify, you're best off dropping the `@Id` annotation and treating embedded entities just like regular embedded objects. There's no reason why `id` can't just be a regular (indexed) property.

Comment: But I cannot drop the `@Id` annotation because every entity has to have one field annotated with `@Id`

Comment: Embedded objects do not need to be `@Entity`. They can be regular POJOs. Actually embedding `@Entity` objects is possible, but it has some what more complicated meaning than what you likely want to do (it sets the key of the EmbeddedEntity). Unless you really know what you are doing, you probably want keyless embedded things.

Comment: But I need them to be `@Entity`, I use them in other part of my code

Comment: In that case, duplicate the id field into a real `@Index`ed field. Populate it in an `@OnSave` method and don't provide any getters or setters so it's hidden from the rest of your code. Keys are special in the datastore and ids, being one component of a key, are not uniquely filterable.